# CFBuilder:- File dissappears from the SS/workspace off and on

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, coldfusionbuilder

What is the issue with CFBuilder?
I am trying to Check out a file from SS/CFBuilder  and all i get is the message

80020009: Network not found.[src=SourceSafe,guid=null]
In fact even perfectly working files that are months old,suddenly become "removed from SS".As a result of which I have only "Team/Commit Changes" option for a given file.The "Team/CheckIn ..CheckOut" options are blanked out.

Also when I am trying to click the "Show Local History",for an pretty old/often used file, it throws an message

```
 No local History available for selected resource!
```

The Same message is coming for each and every file.

Please help.
Vas

Comment: What version of the beta are you running? Beta 3 is out now. Also, take a look at http://blogs.adobe.com/cfbuilder/2009/12/reporting_one-off_issues_with.html for some advice on how to give feedback. This helps improve the product overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely in Eclipse. Eclipse allows you to store local history for the files that have a size lower than 1 MB.

Goto Window >Preferences >General >Workspace >Local History

Increase the Maximum file size so that it is higher than the size of your files.
After applying the change, the next time the file is saved, Eclipse will create a history.